# PHP 'Checkbox' Alternative when updating

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have a small problem with my PHP Code and as always, any help is hugely appreciated.

The code was originally designed by another person and I seem to have come across a problem that I can't fix.

The structure of the page is as follows:

1. A while loop to output the data, each of course, has a unique id.
2. A checkbox that must be ticked before pressing the 'update' button
   (several update buttons present pending on how many rows are
   returned.

This is what i'm confused on, he has designed it to they must tick the 'checkbox' before pressing update, otherwise, the script doesn't know which 'id' to update. Why is it like this?!

```
<?php 
if($_POST['accept']){
    if(!$_POST['check']){
        echo "<div class='error_input'>Error! please tick box to confirm </div>";
}else{
        $form_id=$_POST['fid'];
        $customer=$_POST['customer'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE job SET customer='$customer'WHERE f_id=$form_id ");
echo "<div class='form_ok'>Job has been updated.</div>";
}
?>
```

If I just comment out the check box, and the user clicks the 'accept' button, it doesn't work, so clearly the 'checkbox' is pointing to the unique ID of the row, but I can't see it?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1" required/>
<input type="submit" name="accept" value="Accept Job">
```

My issue is, I want to be able to remove this annoying checkbox, and once the user has pressed 'accept' add the unique ID into a session, which I know can be done by:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
```

As they then get redirected to a pop-up box to which I need this unique ID to pull further data from the database.

I've had a go at implemented this:

```
<input type="submit" name="accept" value="<?php echo"$user_id"; ?>" class="sbutton">
```

which works in a nutshell, how ever, it's not user friendly and I can't access the user_id, when I use the `$_POST` feature, it saves the 'name' field.

I know this is long winded, I hope i've given you enough information, many thanks in advance.

Comment: try without the if else for check i think that will do the trick

Comment: But my problem is though, there are several row's of data that's been displayed, each with their own 'update' button, so when I run the check 'if($_POST['accept'];' how will it know which row to update?

Comment: You could probably just change the checkbox to `<input type="hidden" ... />` and it would always submit the value for the check.

Comment: @Ben Little the checkbox isn't used to store the id, it is simply a confirmation that you actually want to make the change. it gets the id from the $_POST['fid'] variable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is another hidden field in there with the job ID, and each row has it's own `<form>` tags - so if you'll remove the check for the `check` field than you're fine.

Like that:

```
<?php 
if($_POST['accept'])
{
    $form_id=$_POST['fid'];
    $customer=$_POST['customer'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE job SET customer='".$customer."' WHERE f_id=".$form_id);
    echo "<div class='form_ok'>Job has been updated.</div>";
}
?>
```

By the way - it's best that you'll check and secure the values from the $_POST with check for numbers and securing against SQL Injection with mysql_real_escape_string function